# What's a good way to make planks in a pattern from a vertices pattern (see image)

Tags: modeling

I made this plane of vertices

[image]

and I'd like to turn it into a pattern of wood planks.

So far I've tried a solidify modifier resulting in this (great!)

[image]

And then a boolean, but I get this
[image]

I've played with thresholds, boolean modes, offsets and thicknesses but it always results in nothing, missing planks or random messes of faces and vertices. Any ideas/recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the faces in *Edit* mode. Press <kbd>I</kbd> (letter not number) to inset, then press <kbd>I</kbd> again to inset all the individual faces. Only do a small inset so there's a small gap, then without deselecting the faces, press <kbd>P</kbd> and select > *By Selection* to separate your new faces into a new object.

From there you can extrude the faces up, and delete the object containing the filler that you no longer need.

[image]

Comment: I was getting there, lol. I'd used P on the individual faces at somepoint, rejoin and scale by individual origins bc I didn't know about inset. Very useful thank you